# Changing Preference Category background color

Tags: android, preferences

How can I change the background color of PreferenceCategory? I want to change it from gray (on 2.3) or white (on Holo) to green. Is this even possible?

Comment: I want to preserve original styling so defining a custom layout does not do it for me

Comment: also that way I have to declare the layout for every category while theming allos me to do it once for all the application